# Craft CMS with local and flywheel setup?

Tags: setup

I have been using this blog https://medium.com/@madebyraygun/a-quick-and-easy-local-environment-for-craft-3-4fd7c7ff5815 as a reference but I cannot seem to connect to my database and get Craft working? The .dev connection gives me an error and when I click on start site I get a 503? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> The .dev connection gives me an error

Don't know if it'll solve all of your problems, but `.dev` is no longer a valid TLD you can use for local testing since Google made it public: https://domains.google/tld/dev/

Change it over to something like `.test` instead.

Comment: i have changed it to .local but that did not work either

Comment: Are you getting new errors? What's the behavior you're seeing?